# Why are the two definitions of a generating set of a group equivalent?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

$\left( G, \circ \right)$ is a group:

Definition 1: $\left<S\right>$ is a subset such that every element of the group can be expressed as the combination (under the group operation) of finitely many elements of the subset and their inverses.

Definition 2: $\left<S\right>$ is the smallest subgroup of $G$ such that $S \subseteq \left<S\right>$.

Why are the two definitions equivalent?

Comment: In definition 2) you probably mean $S\subseteq\langle S\rangle$

Comment: Definition 2 is badly expressed. What does "smallest" mean, and how do you know that there exists such a smallest subgroup? A more accurate formulation is the intersection of all subgroups $H$  of $G$ such that $S \le H$. Call the subgroups defined by Definitions 1 and 2 $S_1$ and $S_2$, and then show that $S_1 \le S_2$ and $S_2 \le S_1$.

Comment: @drhab You can' really write $S \le \langle S \rangle$, because $\langle S \rangle$ is what we are trying to define. But I've corrected ny comment.

Comment: @drhab I'll edit the post.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks! I'll give it a try

Comment: @DerekHolt Actually my comment was meant for the OP (not for you). His original 'such that $S\subseteq G$' should become 'such that $S\subseteq\langle S\rangle$'. He allready changed by now.

Comment: @drhab But what I said is still true. You cannot use $\langle S \rangle$ in the definition of $\langle S \rangle$.

Comment: I think also definition 1 is wrong: what "the group" are we talking about there? I think that what's needed to be proved here is: first, $\;\langle\,S\,\rangle\;$ as defined is a subgroup, and (2) it is the minimal (wrt set containment)subgroup that contains the set $\;S\;$ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's fix some notation.

1. Let $H_1$ be the subgroup consisting of combinations of elements of $S$ and their inverses.
2. Let $H_2$ be the "smallest" subgroup containing $S$.

When we say "small" in this context, what we mean is that $A$ is "smaller" than $B$ if $A\subseteq B$. A more rigorous formulation of the second definition is something like

3. If $H$ is a subgroup and $S\subseteq H$ then $H_2\subseteq H$. (i.e., $H_2$ is smaller than every subgroup that contains $S$.)

This is the definition I'll work with instead of the second one.

I want to convince you now that $H_1=H_2$. The usual way to do this sort of thing is to show that $H_1\subseteq H_2$ and $H_2\subseteq H_1$.

It should be clear that $H_2\subseteq H_1$, since $H_1$ contains $S$ and $H_2$ is contained in any subgroup that contains $S$, by definition. Conversely, *any* subgroup of $G$ that contains $S$ must also contain all combinations of elements of $S$ and their inverses. This is because a subgroup has to be closed under multiplication and taking inverses. In other words, any subgroup of $G$ that contains $S$ must contain $H_1$, and in particular $H_1\subseteq H_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that a group $G$ and a subset $S\subset G$ are given.

Then the set $S$ is a *generating set*, if $\ldots$

*Definition 1:* $\quad\ldots$ each element $g\in G$ can be written as a finite product of elements from $S\cup S^{-1}$;

*Definition 2:* $\quad\ldots$ any subgroup $H\subset G$ containing the set $S$ is in fact $=G$.

Your definition 1 is correct with the proviso that $\langle S\rangle$ should be replaced by $S$. By $\langle S\rangle$ one commonly denotes the set "generated" by $S$, i.e. the set of products described in the text of definition 1.

Your definition 2 is nonsense: Since  $S\subset\langle S\rangle$ is always true it just says that $\langle S\rangle$ is the smallest subgroup of $G$ – exactly the contrary of the intention.